# Best place to set UILabel font size with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

If I set the font size like this:

```
@implementation MyView

- (instancetype)init {

    self = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:nil options:nil].firstObject;

    if (self) {
        [self loadViews];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)loadViews {

    self.myLabel.font = [self.myLabel.font fontWithSize:20];
}
```

while having `10` in the `.xib` file, it somehow gets reset to the value in the `.xib` file.

I tried setting it in `awakeFromNib` too to no avail.

Comment: viewWillApear ... wouldn't placing there would work?

Answer (score 2):

Try to override layoutSubviews

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.myLabel.font = [self.myLabel.font fontWithSize:20];
}
```

Comment: It worked, but the problem with this is that it would be unnecessarily set multiple times, though it can be fixed with a `BOOL` flag. I still don't understand why isn't this working after initializing the wrapper view, or why was it working before Auto Layout.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to use User Defined Runtime Attributes in Identity inspector.

Make interface for UILabel like this.

```
@interface UILabel (CustomFont)
-(void)setFontName:(NSString *)value;
@end
```

After that implement this like below.

```
@implementation UILabel (CustomFont)
-(void)setFontName:(NSString *)value
{        
   CGFloat newsize = (self.font.pointSize * [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width)/320;
   [self setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:self.font.fontName size:newsize]];
}
@end
```

In this function It will set dynamic value to UILabel according to screen size.

You can assign User defined Runtime attribute like this.

[image]

Comment: I can't use custom `UILabel` subclass in every place.